# Creating SQLite trigger via NHibernate

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

I am creating a SQLite database with NHibernate SchemaExport. I have to add update, delete and insert triggers to the database. Is this possible  with NHibernate or do I have to run SQL scripts for trigger creation manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I realized it is possible to get the Session connection and from there you can run any DDL command you want. In my case it would be:

```
       var commandText = new StringBuilder();
        var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
        commandText.AppendLine("CREATE TRIGGER books_insert_trg AFTER INSERT ON books ");
        commandText.AppendLine("BEGIN");
        commandText.AppendLine("UPDATE books SET sort=title_sort(NEW.title),uuid=uuid4() WHERE id=NEW.id;");
        commandText.AppendLine("END");
        command.CommandText = commandText.ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Auxiliary Database Objects](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object)

For mapping by code, you need to add them directly to the `HbmMapping` that you compile from the mapper:

```
mappingDocument.databaseobject =
    new[]
    {
        new HbmDatabaseObject
        {
            Items = new object[]
            {
                new HbmCreate { Text = new[] { "CREATE TRIGGER ..." } }, 
                new HbmDrop { Text = new[] { "DROP TRIGGER ..." } } } 
            } 
    };
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the better solution, to put the trigger creation together with the mappings. I have a problem, though. I am using NHibernate 3.2 with mapping by code (not fluent NHibernate) and I am not able to figure out how to do it this way. Have you by any chance some sample code how to this without xml mappings?