# How to add a specific .hbm.xml file to nhibernate config to use in export schema

Tags: c#, nhibernate, triggers, fluent, schemaexport

I'm working with nhibernate + fluent, I have this code

```
FluentConfiguration fc = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql()
            .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect>().Driver<NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UsuarioMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(a => string.Concat("Id", a.EntityType.Name)))
                .Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.Format((x, y) => string.Concat("Id", y.Name))))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);
```

This adds the mappings from my map files, later I use the exposed config to export schema

Now I need to add a specific `.hbm.xml` file in order to create a trigger in my db and I don't know how, I've already written the `.hbm.xml` file, it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <database-object>
    <create>
    CREATE TRIGGER borradoUsuario BEFORE DELETE ON activaciones
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN set @idUsuario = OLD.IdUsuario;
    SELECT IdHistorialEstado FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = @idUsuario INTO @IdHistorial;
    SELECT IdDomicilio FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = @idUsuario INTO @idDomicilio;
    DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = @idUsuario;
    DELETE FROM domicilios WHERE IdDomicilio = @IdDomicilio;
    DELETE FROM historialestado WHERE IdHistorialEstado = @idHistorial;
    DELETE FROM detallehistorialestado WHERE idHistorialEstado = @idHistorial;
    DELETE FROM inmobiliarias WHERE IdInmobiliaria = @idUsuario;
    DELETE FROM particulares WHERE IdParticular = @idUsuario;
    DELETE FROM moderadores WHERE IdModerador = @idUsuario;
    END
</create>

<drop>
</drop>
```

i hope i get some help here =/

i've move to another aproach, no i have a class that extends from AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject, it knows the create and drop scripts:

```
public class BorradoUsuarioTrigger : AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject{

    public override string SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema){
//The drop is important, because the shema export calls and executes this twice.   


    return @"
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS borradoUsuarioTrigger;
        DELIMITER $$
        CREATE TRIGGER borradoUsuarioTrigger BEFORE DELETE ON activaciones FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE idHist INTEGER;
            DECLARE idDom INTEGER;
            SET idHist = (SELECT IdHistorialEstado FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.IdUsuario);
            SET idDom = (SELECT IdDomicilio FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.IdUsuario);
            DELETE FROM domicilios WHERE IdDomicilio = @idDom;
            DELETE FROM historialestado WHERE IdHistorialEstado = @idHist;
            DELETE FROM detallehistorialestado WHERE idHistorialEstado = @idHist;
            DELETE FROM inmobiliarias WHERE IdInmobiliaria = OLD.idUsuario;
            DELETE FROM particulares WHERE IdParticular = OLD.idUsuario;
            DELETE FROM moderadores WHERE IdModerador = OLD.idUsuario;
            DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.idUsuario;
        END$$";
    }

    public override string SqlDropString(Dialect dialect, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema){
    return @"DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS borradoUsuarioTrigger";
    }

    public void AddDialectScope(string dialectName){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool AppliesToDialect(Dialect dialect){
    return true;
    }

    public void SetParameterValues(IDictionary<string, string> parameters){
    base.SetParameterValues(parameters);
    }
}
```

i think i'm close to what i need, but it's still not working, i get the following message in the most deep exception:

```
"Parameter @idDom must be defined"
```

i think it's because i'm trying to return a hardcoded string for the sql create script, but i don't know, can somebody help me?

Comment: Mybe this can help you figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916222/creating-sqlite-trigger-via-nhibernate

Answer (score 1):

finally got the answer:

the class that knows the sql scripts looks like this

```
public class BorradoUsuarioTrigger : AbstractAuxiliaryDatabaseObject
{
    public override string SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema){
    //The drop is important, because the shema export calls and executes this twice.   
    this.Parameters.Add("idHist", "(SELECT IdHistorialEstado FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.IdUsuario)");
    this.Parameters.Add("idDom", "(SELECT IdDomicilio FROM Usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.IdUsuario)");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS borradoUsuarioTrigger;");
    builder.AppendLine("CREATE TRIGGER borradoUsuarioTrigger BEFORE DELETE ON activaciones FOR EACH ROW ");
    builder.AppendLine("BEGIN ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM domicilios WHERE IdDomicilio = " + this.Parameters["idDom"] + "; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM historialestado WHERE IdHistorialEstado = " + this.Parameters["idHist"] + "; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM detallehistorialestado WHERE idHistorialEstado = " + this.Parameters["idHist"] + "; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM inmobiliarias WHERE IdInmobiliaria = OLD.idUsuario; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM particulares WHERE IdParticular = OLD.idUsuario; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM moderadores WHERE IdModerador = OLD.idUsuario; ");
    builder.AppendLine("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE IdUsuario = OLD.idUsuario; ");
    builder.AppendLine("END ");

    return builder.ToString();
    }

    public override string SqlDropString(Dialect dialect, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema)
    {
        return @"DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS borradoUsuarioTrigger";
    }

    public void AddDialectScope(string dialectName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool AppliesToDialect(Dialect dialect)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void SetParameterValues(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        base.SetParameterValues(parameters);
    }
}
```

and the fluently configure goes like this:

```
        FluentConfiguration fc = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString).ShowSql()
            .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect>().Driver<NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver>())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UsuarioMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(a => string.Concat("Id", a.EntityType.Name)))
                .Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.Format((x, y) => string.Concat("Id", y.Name))))
            .ExposeConfiguration(conf => conf.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new BorradoUsuarioTrigger()))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema);
```